# how to validate checkbox and radio button in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, radio-button

I am unable to validate the checkbox and radio button. Actually i just need to insert validation for user at least select one thing weather checkbox or radio.
see my code. that's not working for me.

```
<script>
  $(".submit").click(function(){
       var checkBoxCount = $(".jobwork:checkbox:checked").length;
      if($(".jobwork:checkbox:checked").length < 1 || ($("input[name=jobwork]:checked").length <= 0)){
          alert("Please select atlease one jobwork");
          return false;

      };

  })
```

Comment: can you post your html here. Is your button is of type submit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/prop/#entry-examples

```
$(".submit").click(function(){
      var isChecked= $(".jobwork")[0].prop('checked');
      if (!isChecked) {
          alert("Please select atlease one jobwork");
          return false;
      };

  })
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to check **whether the checkboxes has a prop** called `checked` in them. It is **available only if the checkbox is checked.**

```js
$(".submit").click(function(){
      var checked = $(".jobwork").prop('checked');
      if(!checked){
          alert("Please select atlease one jobwork");
          return false;

      };

  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" class="jobwork" name="check">
<input type="checkbox" class="jobwork" name="check">
<input type="checkbox" class="jobwork" name="check">
<br>
<input type="button" class="submit" value="submit">
```